# "lieben es, ~ zu Inf." What is the role of 'es'?

Tags: accusative, infinitive, accusative-and-infinitive

Since a year ago, i am learning German.  
I used to watch 'Peppa Wutz'. 
Today, i found something that i can't understand, when i watched it.

The sentence is..

```
…Peppa und Schorsch kaufen gerne ein. Schorsch liebt es, im Wagen zu sitzen.
```

What is the role of 'es' next 'liebt'?  
 I mean why is the 'es' added?

```
…Peppa und Schorsch kaufen gerne ein. Schorsch liebt, im Wagen zu sitzen.
```

Isn't it impossible?  
I have learnd before, zu Inf. sentences.(Akkusativ)  
For example:

```
Ich hoffe, die Prüfung zu bestehen.
Ich versuche, diese Arbeit möglichst schnell zu beenden.
Ich rate Ihnen, nicht zu langsam zu kommen.
```

But i have not seen 'es' before. Should i add 'es' when it comes to lieben verb? Is it just special case..?

Comment: @Olafant I don't understand exactly the meaning of  "But unlike English, German requires the placeholder for the kind of infinitive construction" of the answer you linked me.. sorry.. :( Does it mean the FE. that i wrote above also need placeholder originally? It says the infinitive construction (with something) needs placeholder but, i've never seen "es" before comma of the infinitive phrase before, without the sentence of lieben. Could you explain of that for me?

Comment: With those phrases with zu plus the infinitive, you sometimes need the placeholder and sometimes don't. There is no definitive rule about when you need it and when you don't. If you have Hammer's German Grammar and Usage then refer to 3.6.2(f), there it lists the words that are generally used with the placeholder.

Comment: @Jacob Lee-Hart So, there are some verbs, which need placeholder and others not. Thanks you for your help!